# How to use tikz to draw polygons with highlighted angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

[image]

I am trying to replicate this figure in latex. Obviously, it is quite easy to do it in Geogebra... but I was wondering if there is a special package we can use to do this sort of figures in latex. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is given (a,b,theta,c,d) / what is searched? That's helpful for the construction.

Comment: nothing, all are variables that can take any value (as possible)

Comment: https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Export_to_LaTeX_(PGF,_PSTricks)_and_Asymptote

Comment: @JimmySabater you can use tikz and tz-euclide also

Comment: If nothing is given or searched, the task is quite unspectacular as it is all about creating the image. You can do this with the commands \coordinate for the corners, \draw for the edges and the library angles for the angles, all of which can be found in the TikZ manual. The whole thing becomes interesting when it is a construction, but then one has to know what is given and what is searched.

Comment: PS: And I doubt that all of the sizes (a, b, theta, c, d) are known or can be chosen arbitrary, so that the picture is correct (with the angles etc.). The more unpleasant alternative is to draw it incorrectly and then write the appropriate symbols on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that *a, b, theta* are given. 
Then like that:

[image]

**€dit:** With the 'sharp right angle', which you want:

```
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=3mm, 
angle eccentricity=0.5, "$\cdot$",
] {right angle =C--P--D};
```

Note, that you can comment out `angle eccentricity=0.5, "$\cdot$"` if you do not want an inner dot.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes, babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{4} %  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{2.5} %  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaA}{33} %  

\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\a*tan(\thetaA)} %  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\b/tan(\thetaA)} %  

\begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=0.7,
font=\footnotesize,
>={Triangle[length=0pt 9,width=0pt 4]}
]
\coordinate[label=left:$A$] (A) at (0,0); 
\coordinate[label=below:$B$] (B) at (\x+\y,0); 
\coordinate[label=left:$D$] (D) at (0,\a); 
\coordinate[label=below:$P$] (P) at (\x,0); 

\draw[] (A) -- (D) node[midway, left]{$a$};
\draw[] (A) -- (P) node[midway, below]{$x$};
\draw[] (P) -- (B) node[midway, below]{$y$};
\draw[] (B) -- +(0,\b) coordinate[label=right:$C$](C) node[midway, right]{$b$};

\draw[] (D) -- (P) node[midway, above]{$c$};
\draw[] (C) -- (P) node[midway, above]{$d$};
\draw[] (C) -- (D);

%% Angles
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=7mm, %angle eccentricity=1.3,
"$\theta$", ->
] {angle =A--D--P};
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=8mm, %angle eccentricity=1.3,
"$\theta$", ->
] {angle =P--D--C};
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=7mm, %angle eccentricity=1.3,
"$\theta$", ->
] {angle =B--P--C};
    
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=3mm, 
angle eccentricity=0.5, "$\cdot$",
] {right angle =C--P--D};
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=3mm, 
angle eccentricity=0.5, "$\cdot$",
] {right angle =P--A--D};
\draw pic [draw, angle radius=3mm, 
angle eccentricity=0.5, "$\cdot$",
] {right angle =C--B--P};

%% Points
\foreach \P in {P} \draw[fill=black!1] (\P) circle (1.75pt);

%% Annotations
\path[local bounding box=figure] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) --cycle;
\node[yshift=-5mm, draw, align=left, fill=lightgray!50,
anchor=north west,  % text width=\x cm+\y cm,
] at (figure.south west) {
$\begin{array}{l l}
a = \a \text{ cm}  &  \\
b = \b \text{ cm}  & \\ 
\theta = \thetaA^\circ   &  \\ \hline \\%[0.1em]
x = a\cdot\tan(\theta)   &  =\x  \text{ cm}    \\ 
y = \dfrac{b}{\tan(\theta)}   &  =\b \text{ cm} \hspace{2.0cm}\\
\end{array}$
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I overseen that there is a `Pic type right angle` (TikZ-manual, p. 569). Maybe since a newer version.

Answer (score 3):

For fun, a pstricks code that mimicks a construction with ruler and compass on a sheet of paper:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-0.1)(5.2,4)
\psset{linestyle=none, PointSymbol=none, PointName=none}%
\pstGeonode(0,0){O}(0,4){B}(8,0){A}
\pstBissectBAC{O}{B}{A}{X} \pstInterLL{B}{X}{O}{A}{C}
\pstSymO{C}{B}[B1]
\pstMediatorAB{B}{B1}{C}{Y}\pstInterLL{A}{B}{C}{Y}{D}
\pstProjection{O}{A}{D}[E]
\psset{linestyle=solid, linejoin=1, linecolor=Coral}
\pspolygon(O)(B)(D)(E)
\psline(B)(C)(D)
%%angles
\psset{linecolor=black, linewidth=0.5pt}
\pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=0.25]{B}{C}{D}
\psset{arrows=->,arrowinset=0.12, MarkAngleRadius=0.7}
\pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{D}{$\theta$}
\pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=0.8]{O}{B}{C}{$\theta$}
\pstMarkAngle{E}{C}{D}{$\theta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]